# Spyder? Copy file absolute or relative path from file explorer

Tags: python, spyder

Is there a way in Spyder-ide to copy a file's absolute or relative path or at least file's name from file explorer in Spyder-ide?

Is it possible also to open multiple file explorers each in a different directory?

Last question? Can an existing directory be converted into a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) These are my answers:

> Is there a way in Spyder-ide to copy a file's absolute or relative path or at least file's name from file explorer in Spyder-ide?

Not right now, but there's work in progress to implement this for Spyder 4, to be released in 2019.

> Is it possible also to open multiple file explorers each in a different directory?

No, it's not possible. But you can open multiple consoles, each one pointing to a different directory and when you switch among them, you'll see the file explorer view is updated automatically.

> Can an existing directory be converted into a project?

Not exactly, but you can create a project in any directory by going to the menu `Projects > New project` and selecting your directory there.